# Issues with grabbing frames from a webcam using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Im working with openCV, and my output window does not show anything (black screen) when I run the code. I am using my default webcam.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main() {
  //simple camera capture program.

  IplImage* newImg;
  CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

  while(1) {
    newImg = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cvShowImage( "src", newImg );

    if (cvWaitKey(15) == 27) { 
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide details such as operating system, and camera vendor information? It will help you get more useful answers.

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10 by chance?

Comment: @mevatron  i am using windows vista along with netbeans.i think my webcam is not supported.i execute the program in my desktop and it works fine.i want to somehow execute it on my laptop.My laptop has a nvidia graphic card.i am tryin to learn cuda for image processing.i read somehere you require to use cuda along with opencv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine.

The problem is most likely specific to your machine, since OpenCV supports only a few cameras. You might want to use some other library to grab frames from the camera - (V4L, for example?).

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the creation of the window for displaing the picture. Before the while add:

```
cvNamedWindow("src");
```